# Android instrument test in gitlab CI/CD runner, installed on a virtual machine

Tags: android, gitlab, android-emulator, instrumented-test

I'm struggling to run an android emulator in a GitLab CICD job.

Right now we have Proxmox virtualization on bare metal which hosts some VMs. One of the VMs is a GitLab runner. The runner uses the docker executor for CICD jobs. So I need to run an android emulator inside a docker container to be able to run instrument tests. Android emulators need a hardware accelerator to start. So I need to enable [nested virtualization on Proxmox](https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Nested_Virtualization) then [use privileged or pass `/dev/kvm` to CICD container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48422001/how-to-launch-qemu-kvm-from-inside-a-docker-container) to be able to run the emulator. But the first step (Proxmox nested virtualization) seems very risky to me right now because we already have many services on Proxmox. I want to ask for ideas on how to solve this problem.

What I have tried so far:

1. Use an android emulator without hardware acceleration. I used `-no-accel` flag and `arm64-v8a` emulators. None of them worked (dead emulator)
2. Install GitLab runner on bare metal. It works. But of course, I don't have another production server :)